# Can the current version of Emberjs.Data be used for projects in production?

Tags: model, ember.js, ember-data

I am looking for a Javascript MVC framework and have found Ember.js. In conjunction with my development team, we decided that it was the one we would use. (For reference, we compared Ember, Backbone, and JavascriptMVC.)

However, as I've dug into the documentation it doesn't really seem to have a clearly defined Model object though there is currently [emberjs/data](https://github.com/emberjs/data) on github. The Data framework is pretty clearly labeled as a work in progress, but I've seen multiple tutorials using it and there seems to be good activity but much of the code base looks like it hasn't been touched in months.

Is it stable enough to use in a production environment? As a caveat, I know that upgrading from one version to the next could introduce breaking bugs that we would have to resolve, but that's not a deal breaker.

Or is there a better (read more mature, better documented) framework out there that we should be looking at?

Comment: You can certainly use, but it's not advised, as per [README in GitHub](https://github.com/emberjs/data#is-it-production-ready%E2%84%A2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official answer is that it's not yet production-ready.

The unofficial answer is that if you stay away from associations, and are up for staying on top of the commits, master is pretty solid.